# Environment texture not effecting model in eevee but working fine in cycles

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am new to blender, not sure if I am doing anything wrong with blender settings or is it a blender bug.

I am trying to increase environment texture strength but, I am not able to get environment texture light effect on model in eevee, but works fine in cycles.

Please refer below images

In **Eevee** environment texture with strength 1
[image]

In **Eevee** environment texture with strength 10
[image]

In **Cycles** environment texture with strength 1
[image]

In **Cycles** environment texture with strength 10
[image]

Appreciate some help. Let me know if any other details required.

**System info** :
Windows 10
16gb ram
Blender 3.0.0 alpha

***faced same issue in other blender versions too***

[Attaching the video link which will help you to understand issue I am facing.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bxsqvI-RbMs3bCZWE_DdU9BoRmjf60C6/view?usp=sharing)

[Google drive link to blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T54gBlvGb219I7r1iNgKgWHnjLrnkWM_/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: A blend file would be useful along with some step by step instructions, rather than asking people to watch a video. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MartyFouts I have updated question with drive link for blend file. I am not able to upload blend file in the link provided by you since its 76 MB.  Let me know if anything more detail you need. Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: EEVEE has environment lighting, but no shadows are cast from it, unlike Cycles. Is that what we are talking about (screenshots of the difference between the two would help)

Comment: @TheLabCat I have now attached screenshots for both Eevee and cycles. I want to achieve environment light effect in eevee.

Comment: Thx, that’s much more clear :-) Hmm, this is odd. That is an environment texture node and not just a regular image texture node, right?

Comment: @TheLabCat Ha yes its environment texture node

Comment: I suspect this is a bug, so not your fault.

Comment: Make sure that you didn't have any indirect light bake, if you did, you just need to go to the render setting > Indirect Lighting >Delete Lighting Cache.

Comment: @Emir Thank you so much. Deleting Lighting Cache worked for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.